# Why I am always getting "inexistent-host" error?

Tags: ejabberd

I installed **ejabberd 20.07** on Ubuntu and set domain name as **faiqkhan-VirtualBox** and set user-admin name as **admin** and password to **123456**. I also check install.log file it shows
**User admin@faiqkhan-VirtualBox successfully registered**. I also checked using command `./ejabberctl registered_users faiqkhan-VirtualBox` it returns my user name **admin**. I don't know why it always giving error **Access of <<"admin@faiqkhan-VirtualBox">> from <<"::ffff:127.0.0.1">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-host">>** while logging in.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the given URL http://localhost:5280/admin/ to my host http://faiqkhan-VirtualBox:5280/admin/ I successfully logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states the host (**@domain**) is non-existent.

You will need to add it to your `ejabberd.yml` under `hosts` e.g. for **localhost**:

```
hosts:
  - "faiqkhan-VirtualBox"
  - "localhost"
```

Or for **admin@faiqkhan.com** (username **admin** and hostname **faiqkhan.com**)

```
hosts:
  - "faiqkhan-VirtualBox"
  - "faiqkhan.com"
```

Cheers